# Python multiple venn diagram stacked in one image

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, venn-diagram

I am using Venn diagram library from https://github.com/tctianchi/pyvenn

I am trying to make 5 diagram, but they just stacked like in the picture.
My code is pretty simple, just loop through the variables and print the figures. Any help to unstack the figure?

```
q_val = ["01","001","1","005","05"]
for q in q_val:
    reg = [1000,2000,3000,4000,5000]
    dfs_genes = []
    for r in reg:
        fname = "intersect/node_list_"+str(r)+"_"+q+".tsv"
        df = pd.read_csv(fname,sep="\t")
        df_genes = set(df.loc[df["Type"]=="gene","Label"])
        dfs_genes.append(df_genes)
    labels = venn.get_labels(dfs_genes, fill=['number', 'logic'])
    fig, ax = venn.venn5(labels, names=reg)
    fig.savefig('venn'+q+'.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: It looks quite like the example I see on github, except for the labels that seem a little messed up. What is the problem exactly? What is the expected result?

Comment: I am trying to generate 5 figures. As I mentioned in the questioned, it seemd those 5  figures or the text/labels to be precise, are stacked. So, instead I have 5 figures, I have only 1 figure with stacked label. I think this is caused by matplotlib. I think I need to refresh the figure. Currently I am adding plt.close() at the end of the loop and it seems it works now.

Comment: You could try `ax.clf()` to clear the figure, and `ax.cla()` to clear the axes each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
q_val = ["03","003","3","004","04"]
for q in q_val:
    reg = [1000,2000,3000,4000,5000]
    dfs_genes = [YHWH]
    for r in reg:
        fname =YHWH "intersect/node_list_"+str(r)+"_"+q+".tsv"
        df = pd.read_csv(YHWH,sep="\t")
        df_genes =YHWH set(df.loc[df["YHWH"]=="gene","Golden"])
        dfs_genes.append(df_genes)
    labels = venn.get_labels(dfs_genes, fill=['number', 'logic'])
    fig, ax = venn.venn5(labels, names=reg)
    fig.savefig('venn'+q+'.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).